# Trouble calling on a Java method from a native thread using JNI (C++)

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I have a JNI problem which I hope someone can help me out with.
I'm trying to call on a constructor of a Java class called LUSOutputJNI from a native thread.
It keeps failing on FindClass(...) of this specific class.

Here is the code:

```
 LOGE("1");
    JNIEnv *env = NULL;

    LOGE("2");
    int res = -1;
    res = g_vm->AttachCurrentThread(&env, NULL);

    if(env == NULL)
    {
        LOGE("env is NULL, AttachCurrentThread failed");;
    }


    if(res >= 0)
        LOGE("AttachCurrentThread was successful");
    jclass clazz = NULL;
    jmethodID cid;

    jclass clazzESEngine;
    jmethodID callbackid;

    jobject jCoreOut;
    static jfieldID fid_ActionState = NULL;
    static jfieldID fid_nSpeed = NULL;
    static jfieldID fid_nType = NULL;
    static jfieldID fid_nInProcess = NULL;
    static jfieldID fid_nX = NULL;
    static jfieldID fid_nY = NULL;
    LOGE("3");

    static const char* const ECOClassName = "lus/android/sdk/LUSOutputJNI";
    //static const char* const ECOClassName = "android/widget/TextView";
    clazz = env->FindClass(ECOClassName);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        LOGE("Can't find class LUSOutputJNI");

    }
    else
        LOGE("lus/android/sdk/LUSOutputJNI was found, YEY!!");

    LOGE("4");
    cid = env->GetMethodID(clazz,"<init>", "()V");
    LOGE("5");
    jCoreOut = env->NewObject(clazz, cid);

    LOGE("6");
```

**Here is the logcat output from when it fails:**

```
E/lusCore_JNI( 3040): 1
E/lusCore_JNI( 3040): 2
E/lusCore_JNI( 3040): AttachCurrentThread was successful
E/lusCore_JNI( 3040): 3
E/lusCore_JNI( 3040): Can't find class LUSOutputJNI
E/lusCore_JNI( 3040): 4
W/dalvikvm( 3040): JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception raised
```

**Observations:**

- I get a result from AttachCurrentThread which is 0, which means that this attachment was successful + the env pointer is no longer NULL.
- I'm sure about the package name declaration of LUSOutputJNI (triple checked it...)
- When I try to run FindClass(..) with a more popular class name such as android/widget/TextView , I get a positive match. It is there. Meaning the thread attachment and the env variables are ok. (Can I assume that?)
- When I try to run the following code from a JNI method which has a JNI thread running it, it finds the LUSOutputJNI class without a problem.

What am I doing wrong?

Help will be much appreciated :)

Thanks for your time,

Ita

Comment: Any reference to this 'LUSOutputJNI' class?

Comment: @K-ballo: It's probably an in-house class.

Comment: @Ita: Is your LUSOutputJNI static initialiser throwing an exception? You should print the exception raised.

Comment: @lta you should fix your error handling.  It made me cry.

Comment: Is LUSOutputJNI in the classpath?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found the answer \ work around in here. (Look for FAQ: "FindClass didn't find my class" in 
[JNI tips](http://www.milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/jni-tips.html))

I basicaly saved a global ref to the needed jclass objects.
Did however had to overcome some evil JNI changes between C/JNI and C++/JNI in order for the code to compile.
This is how I got the NewGlobalRef to compile and work.

```
jclass localRefCls = env->FindClass(strLUSClassName);
if (localRefCls == NULL) {
    LOGE("Can't find class %s",strLUSCoreClassName);
    return result;
}

//cache the EyeSightCore ref as global
 /* Create a global reference */
 clazzLUSCore = (_jclass*)env->NewGlobalRef(localRefCls);

 /* The local reference is no longer useful */
 env->DeleteLocalRef(localRefCls);

 /* Is the global reference created successfully? */
 if (clazzLUSCore == NULL) {
     LOGE("Error - clazzLUSCore is still null when it is suppose to be global");
     return result; /* out of memory exception thrown */
 }
```

I hope this helps anyone.

Comment: Thanks, this helped. Is it really necessary to delete the local ref here? I believe they are automatically deleted when the function returns: http://android-developers.blogspot.co.il/2011/11/jni-local-reference-changes-in-ics.html

Answer (score 2):

To get a bit more information about whats going wrong ( it will log to stderr, not LOGE, and I'm not sure how to change that) you can add some exception printing - you can change this:

```
//static const char* const ECOClassName = "android/widget/TextView";
clazz = env->FindClass(ECOClassName);
if (clazz == NULL) {
    LOGE("Can't find class LUSOutputJNI");

}
else
    LOGE("lus/android/sdk/LUSOutputJNI was found, YEY!!");
```

To this:

```
    //static const char* const ECOClassName = "android/widget/TextView";
    clazz = env->FindClass(ECOClassName);
    if (clazz == NULL) {
        LOGE("Can't find class LUSOutputJNI");
        jthrowable exc = env->ExceptionOccurred();
        if(exc)
        {
          env->ExceptionDescribe();
          env->ExceptionClear();
        }    
    }
    else
        LOGE("lus/android/sdk/LUSOutputJNI was found, YEY!!");
```

Comment: Looks like you can get the error info using the toString function inside the jthrowable, and then convert that to a C string and put that into your `LOGE` function, but that may be overkill for debugging this.